# Why do I get the following error? Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

namespace Variance

{
  class A { }

  class B : A { }

  class C<out T>  { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v = new C<B>();

        CA(v);
    }

    static void CA(C<A> v) { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is the offending line:

```
class C<out T>
```

As the error message tells you, you can't apply generic variance to classes, only to interfaces and delegates. This would be okay:

```
interface C<out T>
```

The above is not.

For details, see [Creating Variant Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)

Comment: "you can't apply generic variance to classes" - but why?

Answer (score 5):

You're attempting to apply generic variance to a class.  This is not supported.  It is only supported on interfaces and delegate types.

Illegal:

```
class C<out T>  { }
```

Legal:

```
interface C<out T> {}
```